# Default.aspx contents don't showup when i run windows azure web role project?

Tags: azure

I have just created simple hello world application on windows azure and trying to run it on my local Pc using windows 7, but Default.aspx page name appears in address bar of web browser. Page contents don't showup.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is completely blank this [blog](http://scottdensmore.typepad.com/blog/2010/05/how-a-checkbox-saved-paving-my-machine.html) by Scott Densmore may help, it solved my problems.